# Apple iPhone Calendar issue

Tags: iphone

Somehow the calendar on my phone is showing only the 2015 yearly calendar. How do I get back to seeing daily schedule?

Answer (score 1):

normaly it would be like this:

```
Launch the Calendar app on your iPhone.
By default, you'll normally see a month view.

Tap on the list button in the top navigation to combine month view with a summary view underneath it.
```

Any day you tap on will then show all the events for that day underneath it.

```
Tap the month in the upper left to pan out to year view.

Alternately, from month view, you can also tap any day on the calendar to view a day view. Keep in mind that in order for day view to work, you need to have the list option turned off in month view.

Lastly, tap the list button in the top of day view in order to view a scrollable endless stream of all of your events.
```